# Does git pull retrieves all of the remote's data?

Tags: git

I know that `git fetch` will retrieve all the branches from the remote repository into your local database (.git directory), but will not merge any branch with your local branch. I also know that `git pull` retrieves the remote branch that is tracked by the current checked-out branch from the remote repository and merge it's changes into your local branch.
But does `git pull` also retrieves the new data from the other branches into the local database (.git directory)?

Example:

I have branch **master** and branch **feature** in my remote repository. I clone the repository to my local computer using `git clone https://www.someserver.com/repo.git`. Now, `git clone` automatically checked-out for me the **master** branch and told it to track **origin/master**. After a few days I use `git pull` to update my local repository. It automatically updated **origin/master** and merged it into my local **master**. But did it also update **origin/feature**? (e.g. I know have the latest version of **feature** branch on the remote repository in my local **origin/feature** branch?)

**Bonus question:**

If use a manual backup system of sorts for my remote repositories (using `git clone`), how would I update them?

Comment: The git pull command is actually a shortcut for git fetch followed by the git merge or the git rebase command depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, no it does not. It only pulls master. That's why you have `git fetch ....` and `git remote update ....` commands. The latter one is quite useful when you have many remotes.

Please note that even if `feature` on `origin` was fully meged into `master` on `origin`, then pulling master will surely pull also that merged content but only to the master branch, and it will pull only as many commits as needed to (re)build the relevant history on your side. So commits from `feature` may actually be pulled.

But your tracking reference called `origin/feature` and your local `feature` branch will not be updated by such `git pull origin master`.